# scraping data from ITU download links with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am wanting to get the download links for each of the files on the website https://datahub.itu.int/indicators/ but am struggling to get what I need.

Each indicator seems to contain a direct link to download the data in the following format `https://api.datahub.itu.int/v2/data/download/byid/XXX/iscollection/YYY` where `XXX` is some sort of number between 1 and 100,000+ or so and `YYY` is either `true` or `false`.

Ideally, I would like to get the link to each indicator and a corresponding name/html text of the link in one big dataframe.

I have tried to get the links for the files using `rvest` and various combinations of `html_nodes` and `html_attrs` and xpaths. but have not had any luck. I really want to avoid running a loop and brute force 100,000+ download links because that is horribly inefficient and will almost certainly cause issues for their servers.

I am not sure if there is a better way than using rvest, but any help would be most appreciated.

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

page = "https://datahub.itu.int/indicators/"
read_html(page) %>%
  html_attr("href")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the requests the pages makes (e.g. in the browser devtools) you will find that there is a request to an api which retrieves all the link; from this you can build the urls yourself: (the other solution would be to use `RSelenium`, but this would be much more complicated)

```r
library(httr)
library(tidyverse)

GET("https://api.datahub.itu.int/v2/dictionaries/getcategories") %>%
  content() %>%
  map(as_tibble) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  unnest_wider(subCategory) %>%
  unnest(items) %>%
  unnest_wider(items) %>%
  mutate(url = paste0("https://api.datahub.itu.int/v2/data/download/byid/",
                      codeID,
                      "/iscollection/",
                      tolower(as.character(isCollection)))) %>%
  select(category, codeID, label, subCategory, isCollection, url)
#> # A tibble: 181 × 6
#>    category     codeID label                      subCategory isCollection url  
#>    <chr>         <int> <chr>                      <chr>       <lgl>        <chr>
#>  1 Connectivity   8941 Households with a radio    Access      FALSE        http…
#>  2 Connectivity   8965 Households with a TV       Access      FALSE        http…
#>  3 Connectivity 100002 Households with multichan… Access      TRUE         http…
#>  4 Connectivity   8749 Households with telephone… Access      FALSE        http…
#>  5 Connectivity  20719 Individuals who own a mob… Access      FALSE        http…
#>  6 Connectivity  12046 Households with a computer Access      FALSE        http…
#>  7 Connectivity  12047 Households with Internet … Access      FALSE        http…
#>  8 Connectivity 100001 Households with access to… Access      TRUE         http…
#>  9 Connectivity 100000 Reasons for not having In… Access      TRUE         http…
#> 10 Connectivity     15 Fixed-telephone subscript… Access      FALSE        http…
#> # … with 171 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thankyou so much! That's exactly what I'm looking for. Plus, it's quick and clean code. Would you mind elaborating a little further on how you actually found that GET link in the first place? I noticed there was an API link from mousing over the download link, but I'm just not entirely clear on how you got the specific url in the first place and would like to understand a little more. Thankyou again.

Comment: If you open the developer tools of your browser (`Ctrl + Shift + I`), you find a tab called "network" which lists all kinds of requests the site does to any kind of server. Most of the times data is returned in JSON format, so you can look out for that. Then click around for the correct Response, and then use this url (right-click onto the response). Sometimes you can find the request already in your Browser console. There are actually many tutorials out there that can teach you this, just search for "webscraping hidden api" e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqtlR0y0suo)

Comment: Thankyou for the quick response, the explanation and the link. Really appreciate it. You've provided a great solution, but, more importantly, have helped me learn. I have managed to find the link and have a much better understanding of how to go about the process now. Thankyou :)